# Use classes from a non executable jar in an executable jar

Tags: java, ant, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I am trying to uses classes from a non executable jar called *noexec.jar* in an executable jar called *exec.jar*. With no defined manifest in the nonexec jar and a manifest in the exec jar. The folder structure where the jars are held look like so.

```
ROOT
 /lib
 |
  ---nonexec.jar
  ---exec.jar
```

With the class path defined in the manifest for the executable jar as `Class-Path: nonexec.jar` such as in [this java link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html). However every time I run `java -jar exec.jar`, I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: helper`. Does anyone what even though I am including nonexec in my class path why the classes contained within the jar are not being found?

EDIT: This is the manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: start
```

Comment: Is `nonexec` also the name of the class file you're `import`ing?

Comment: sorry no it is not I copied that down wrong. it is helper.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `nonexec.jar` to the class path in your manifest, i. e.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: nonexec.jar
Main-Class: start
```

If you just use `Class-Path: .` the current directory (`.`) is searched for classes.
If you need more than one jar on the class path list them all separated with a space:

```
Class-Path: nonexec.jar nonexec2.jar nonexec3.jar
```

Comment: Do you know what the manifest for a non executable jar should look like?

Comment: It also has a package name of test, so it is looking for test.helper for the class to run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58989/discussion-between-ralf-wagner-and-jgr208).